# Should we reopen the "Tips for golfing in Befunge 93" question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, reopening, tips

I'm referring to this question: [Tips for golfing in Befunge 93](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/49891/62101)

It's currently closed as a duplicate of ["Tips for golfing in Befunge 98"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/16090/62101), but they're really not the same language - they're probably about as similar as C and C++. While there's obviously a fair amount of overlap, more than half of the current Befunge 98 tips are specific to 98. And there'd almost certainly be tips that were specific to Befunge 93, if only there were some place to post them.

That said, I'd be OK with the two questions remaining merged if we could at least change the title of the question to remove the reference to "98". And ideally the answers that are specific to Befunge-98 should also be marked as such. However, that solution was already proposed nearly four years ago, and nothing has been done about it, so it looks like the original poster is just not willing to go that route.

So what's the next step?

- Do I make the changes to all the posts myself and risk an edit war
  with the original author?
- Do I leave things as they are and just not
  post tips for Befunge-93?
- Or can we possibly consider reopening the
  ["Tips for golfing in Befunge
  93"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/49891/62101) topic and
  treat them as separate languages?

Comment: I'd edit the 98 to be "tips for golfing in befunge".

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## Edit 'Tips for Befunge 98' to be general Befunge tips

I think the solution for this would be to merge the two versions into one 'language' as far as tips are concerned. This is how it is normally done, for example there is a ["Tips for Golfing in Python"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/54/60919), where both Python 2 and Python 3 specific tips are posted.

Comment: I'd be happy to accept this answer, but I'd like to get a clearer indication that this is the consensus (i.e. more upvotes), before I start changing the content of someone else's post.

Comment: @JamesHolderness Relevant: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13067/45941

Comment: Forgot to mention, this has my upvote (can't vote)

Comment: @FlipTack That's a thing that was often done back in 2014 ("this has my upvote"), but you don't really need to mention it, you only post an opinion if you agree with it, and upvotes indicate agreement with a particular opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback everyone. I think this is a good enough indication of consensus, so I've made the change now.